# includes inside a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

Is the following approach correct? Well i get a compilation error.

a.hpp is

```
#include <iostream>

class a
{

public:

void classa_f();


};
```

a.cpp is

```
#include "a.hpp"


void a::classa_f()
{

   std::cout<< "a::classa_f\n";


}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
namespace myname {
#include "a.hpp"
}

int main ()

{

   myname::a obj;
   obj.classa_f();

  return 0;

}
```

I get the following error

g++ main.cpp a.o
/tmp/ccOOf5s7.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to`myname::a::classa_f()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Well my question is,  is it possible to have just the includes under the namespace but not the actual implementation, because I can see that compiler is searching the namespace for he definition of the function.which is actually not there.

Comment: Why are you including it within a namespace?

Comment: The solutions suggested in the answers are of course correct, but if you want to stick with your approach, you should then define `a::classa_f()` by qualifying it with the name of the namespace, ie `void myname::a::classa_f(){/...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace myname {
    #include "a.hpp"
}
```

Declares a class method `myname::a::classa_f` , which obviously doesn't exist in your program. It's not valid.

Answer (score 0):

In the implementation, you must

```
namespace myname
{
    void a::classa_f()
    {
        std::cout<< "a::classa_f\n";
    }
}
```

and please remove `#include <iostream>` from the hpp file, it gets imported into the namespace too.

Comment: I am having trouble reconciling "don't include <iostream> in the hpp file, it gets imported into the namespace" with the design pinciple "header files should include anything they depend on".